# How to set custom page size in mPDF? Mpdf version7

Tags: php, mpdf

I am using mpdf library in PHP to create a pdf file from HTML. I need to set the page mode in Custom mode

Answer (score 9):

**[mPDF 7.x]** See `format` parameter and Example #2 on [mPDF __construct documentation page](https://mpdf.github.io/reference/mpdf-functions/construct.html):

```
// Define a page size/format by array - page will be 190mm wide x 236mm height
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf(['format' => [190, 236]]);
```

The format is an array of width and height in millimeters.

Answer (score 3):

```
$mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf(['mode' => 'utf-8', 'format' => 'A4']);
```

you can change your file size using these code lines (A4/A3/A2....) when declaring the mpdf class.
for more information [click here](https://mpdf.github.io/paging/page-size-orientation.html)

Answer (score 0):

Please see this example code -

```
$mpdf=new mPDF('utf-8', array(190,236)); // Define a page size/format by array - page will be 190mm wide x 236mm height
```

add options like this:

```
$mpdf = new mPDF('',    // mode - default ''
 '',    // format - A4, for example, default ''
 0,     // font size - default 0
 '',    // default font family
 15,    // margin_left
 15,    // margin right
 16,     // margin top
 16,    // margin bottom
 9,     // margin header
 9,     // margin footer
 'L');  // L - landscape, P - portrait
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to reduce the edge of the barcodes a bit. This code helped

[image]

```
$mpdf = new Mpdf([
    "tempDir" => public_path("tmp"),
    "mode" => "utf-8",
    "margin_left" => 5,
    "margin_right" => 5,
    "margin_top" => 5,
    "margin_bottom" => 5,
    "margin_header" => 5,
    "margin_footer" => 5,
]);
```

See Mpdf.php

```
private function initConstructorParams(array $config)
{
    $constructor = [
        'mode' => '',
        'format' => 'A4',
        'default_font_size' => 0,
        'default_font' => '',
        'margin_left' => 15,
        'margin_right' => 15,
        'margin_top' => 16,
        'margin_bottom' => 16,
        'margin_header' => 9,
        'margin_footer' => 9,
        'orientation' => 'P',
    ];

    foreach ($constructor as $key => $val) {
        if (isset($config[$key])) {
            $constructor[$key] = $config[$key];
        }
    }

    return array_values($constructor);
}
```